# How to read RSA public key from file/string in java/kotlin using BouncyCastle

Tags: kotlin, bouncycastle

I am trying to parse a public key in the RSA format from kotlin.  I have the key in a string whose contents are like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAwAzOKC8d0o0dcv1KqILLehASGgOWyjlAc+adazix6ThhX7QeD3Qw
HzxPpbwsJrVPIEMEIN383awIqnCfIL+AbCQPL13XaUCCS74wC5a84X1r6hcI5XO1
9CPAn+jBKmTr4hPaHWKxuhfO3PcXxGfQdXyqNT96bCYnAYaeSECohFjqDbe+RFcL
1lIns2GtQPMh1/uDyhPA+8HSguREWn+Ac3I2c0wtrzZa6R4nruPgIi6XbWRqAskr
tzbO2Xy6O1DcERH9tg+es/pbrWHRHrwEmLXorj3iGqkJJBUmLeW6B5EjmIgiukdJ
dw7bLTNcwf2n0BLJy/bgnhcw4TMOzUadSQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I found a lot of code examples to do this that involve trimming out the BEGIN and END, using String.replace() but that seemed hacky to me.  The [BouncyCastle code seems to handle this already](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMParser.java) including the ability to create a parsers for the different types of "files" it encounters.  I'm trying this:

```
try {
    val parser = PEMParser(StringReader(publicKeyString))
    val pemObject = parser.readPemObject()
    val pemContent = pemObject.content
    val key = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey.getInstance(pemContent)
    serviceLogger.info("Key object: {}", key)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    serviceLogger.error("Could not generate key from keyspec", e)
}
```

I get as far as a pemContent (an array of bytes) without a problem, but when I try to actually parse that into an RSAPublicKey I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DEF length 3 object truncated by 2
```

What I can't figure out is if I'm calling RSAPublicKey.getInstance() correctly - with the content of the entire PemObject - or is this exception telling me that there's something wrong with my key.

The examples I have been able to find on this are pretty old, and the APIs seem to have evolved to the point that I shouldn't have to be chopping up strings manually.

I doubt this really helps the matter, but I'm generating this file in go from an rsa keypair:

```
func PublicKeyToPemBytes(prvkey *rsa.PrivateKey) ([]byte, error) {
    var pubkey *rsa.PublicKey
    pubkey = &prvkey.PublicKey

    pubkey_bytes := x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(pubkey)
    if pubkey_bytes == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Public key could not be serialized")
    }

    pubkey_pem := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "RSA PUBLIC KEY",
            Bytes: pubkey_bytes,
        },
    )

    return pubkey_pem, nil
}
```

The go rsa.PublicKey object contains an N and an E.  It gives me a file like listed above, and the base64 decoding results in the exact same length, 270 bytes.

Comment: Did you alter the data as well as truncating it? Parts of it could be in a valid PKCS1-RSAPublicKey, more than could occur by chance, but other parts are quite wrong. This format is very rarely used by itself nowadays and I'm surprised go does; Bouncy supports it only because OpenSSL does -- and OpenSSL does so only partially, as a relic from the last century. That said, if you have valid data, Bouncy should work. (Also OpenSSL.) Could you post a complete key, even a test one? Remember the point of public-key crypto is the public key is not secret and can be known even to the enemy.

Comment: Right, fair point.  I modified the original post to include a complete key.  I definitely had a problem with my key generation - it was generating integers with ASN.1 type 0x62 instead of 0x02.  I fixed that, and so the above example is acceptable to both dumpasn1 and 'openssl asn1parse'

Comment: Using your posted key, and Javafying your code (which means it's almost verbatim), I get no exceptions and get the expected output.

Comment: Dave, what format is better?  I don't want to store it as an actual certificate (at least I don't think so) ... I'm just trying to store and pass around the public half of an RSA keypair in some reasonable format.

Comment: Clunky as it seems, using an X.509/PKIX cert -- if you don't have a real CA-issued one then a dummy self-signed one -- is in fact a common and conventional way of handling a public key (excepting, importantly, for PGP and SSH). If you don't want to do that, use the 'SubjectPublicKeyInfo' structure _from_ X.509 -- that's what OpenSSL uses by default since about 2000, and Java `Key` and `KeyFactory` (asymmetric) support it directly -- in DER (aka binary) not PEM, but converting between those without needing to change the data is easy enough even without Bouncy.

Answer (score 0):

dave_thompson_085 was right.  This code actually does work.  He asked me if I altered the data, which made me look more closely at it and I realized I was doing a .toUpperCase() on the base64.  The result was still perfectly valid base64 with some bits flipped on here and there.  I shouldn't have been doing that .toUpperCase() at all, I just didn't see it until he said that.  Bouncy does work.